# union memory allocation :: stores more content than allocated memory

Tags: c, memory-management, struct, unions

I have defined a union as

```
union person
{
    int roll;
    char fname[10];
    char lname[20];


}p1;
```

And the sizeof(p1)=20 bytes.
but while storing the content in p1 its storing more than 20 chars.

```
void main()
{
    printf("\n The size of the union is %zu\t",sizeof(p1));
    printf("\n Enter the details here :\t");
    scanf("%d",&p1.roll);
    scanf("%s",p1.fname);
    scanf("%s",p1.lname);
    printf("\n The union contains are \n");
    printf("\n The roll no is :: \t %d",p1.roll);
    printf("\n The fname is :: \t %s ",p1.fname);
    printf("\n The laname is :: \t %s\n",p1.lname);


}
```

when i give input more than 20 char,still its stored.

Answer (score 3):

> when i give input more than 20 char,still its stored.

Of course it is. Why wouldn't it? You handed `scanf` a pointer and basically said "write as many chars here as you possibly wish!"

```
scanf("%9s",p1.fname);
scanf("%19s",p1.lname);
```

That will prevent `scanf` from overrunning the buffer. Note that I've subtracted one from each length, as `scanf` needs to write a NUL terminator as well.

Now, the next problem: Why are you using a `union`? A union is used to provide different views of the same data. Writing to one member effectively trashes the contents of all others. `union`s are used very rarely, in constrast to `struct`s.

If you want to store multiple related pieces of information, use a `struct`.

```
struct person
{
    int roll;
    char fname[10];
    char lname[20];
} p1;
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to Jonathon's answer, I would point out that the *reason* more than 20 chars is stored is because `scanf` has no idea about your union.

When you declare the union

```
union person
{
    int roll;
    char fname[10];
    char lname[20];

}p1;
```

and say

```
scanf("%s",p1.lname);
```

all `scanf` sees is that you have it a `char *` to store the string into.  It *doesn't* see a `char[20]`.

In other words, the additional information that you as a programmer know - that `p1.lname` is only 20 characters - is not visible to `scanf`.

Generally, in C, it's up to you as the programmer to ensure that you don't go around reading or writing more data than your buffers can handle.